# Syntax for linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to make a linked list for my C++ class and I was looking at some code from my professor:

```
void List::add(char c)
{
    Node    *newNode(new Node(c));

    if (last == nullptr)
        first = last = newNode;
    else {
        last->next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        }
}

int List::find(char c)
{
    Node    *node(first);
    int     i(0);

    while (node) {
        if (node->c == c)
            return i;
        node = node->next;
        i++;
        }
    return -1;
```

The following is the class declaration from the header file:

```
class List
{
public:
    List(void);
    ~List(void);
    void add(char c);
    int find(char c);
    bool remove(int index);
    int length(void);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, List& list);

private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(char c) : c(c), next(nullptr) { }
        char    c;
        Node    *next;
    };

    Node    *first;
    Node    *last;
};
```

First question: what do the parentheses mean and what is the correct way to use them?

```
Node    *newNode(new Node(c));
Node    *node(first);
int     i(0);
```

Second question: What does the following mean?

```
Node(char c) : c(c), next(nullptr) { }
```

I have defined a node in the past using a struct; is the syntax different because this is a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statements

```
Node    *newNode(new Node(c));
Node    *node(first);
int     i(0);
```

are equivalent to

```
Node    *newNode = new Node(c);
Node    *node = first;
int     i = 0;
```

This constructor of the class Node

```
Node(char c) : c(c), next(nullptr) { }
```

uses mem-initializer list `: c(c), next(nullptr)` to initialize data members of the class.
That is data member `c` is initialized by constructor parameter `c` and data member `next` is initialized by pointer literal `nullptr`

Comment: Thank you! Once I get more reputation I will be able to upvote your answer.